# How to associate two objects in a HABTM relationship via an AJAX POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm unable to associate one object with another object in a HABTM relationship, only when creating a new object via JSON POST (the relationship works as expected when using the Rails console).

To reproduce: I created a sample project with Videos (has title and URL) and Playlists (has name):

```
rails new videotest
cd videotest
rails g scaffold video title:string url:string
rails g scaffold playlist name:string
rails g migration create_playlists_videos playlist_id:integer video_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

I set the *has_and_belongs_to_many* relationships between the models:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
end
```

In the video controller I white-list the playlist_ids parameter:

```
def video_params
  params.require(:video).permit(:title, :url, playlist_ids: [])
end
```

Then create some sample objects in a rails console:

```
Video.create!(title:"video1", url:"http://youtube.com/123")
Video.create!(title:"video2", url:"http://youtube.com/456")

@playlist = Playlist.create(name:"playlist1")
@playlist.videos.append([Video.first, Video.second])
```

`Playlist.first.videos.count` returns 2 as expected, showing that the HABTM relationship is correctly configured.

I can successfully create a new Video object using an AJAX POST request, where I've also hardcoded the ID of the first playlist:

```
data =   JSON.stringify({
  "title": "test video",
  "url": "http://www.youtube.com/987",
  "playlist_ids": [1]
});

$.ajax({
  url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/videos.json",
  type:"POST",
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  data: data,
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log("added " + msg.title)
  }
});
```

**Problem: the playlist_id isn't used and the resulting Video object isn't associated with Playlist 1.**

The `create` method includes:

```
def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
```

I notice that `video_params` doesn't include playlist_id, but `params` does:

```
(byebug) video_params
{"title"=>"test video", "url"=>"http://www.youtube.com/987"}
(byebug) params[:playlist_ids]
[1]
```

Why isn't `playlist_ids` getting through the whitelist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those associations are set up properly, your Playlist model should have a video_ids attribute, and your Video model should have a playlist_ids attribute.

You can pass these through the form, and rails should create the corresponding records in your playlists_videos link table.

So in your **VideosController** set up your whitelist like so:

```
def video_params
  params.require(:video).permit(:title, :url, playlist_ids: [])
end
```

Now tweak your ajax call to pass through an array of playlist_ids like so:

```
JSON.stringify({ "video": {"title": title, "url": "http://www.youtube.com", "playlist_ids": [1,2]}})
```

Remember to nest the parameters inside the "video" node.

So in this case, you are going to associate the video with both playlist_id 1 and playlist_id 2, for example.

Comment: Many thanks - that fixed it. If I'm ever in the same town as you, I'd love to buy you a beer ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`habtm`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many), you get several methods which you should use:

[image]

Specifically, if you want to set the `playlist_id` of the `video` at create, you'll be best populating the `playlist_ids` attribute:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/videos.json",
  type:"POST",
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  data: JSON.stringify({"title": title, "url": "http://www.youtube.com", "playlist_ids": [1]}),
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log("added " + msg.title)
  }
});

#app/controllers/videos_controllers.rb
class VideosController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @video = Video.new video_params
      @video.save
   end

   private

   def video_params
      params.require(:video).permit(:title, :url, playlist_ids: [])
   end
end
```

This will override the current `playlists` your `video` is associated with; meaning if you want to *add*/*remove* the video to a playlist, you'd be best using the `<<` and `.delete` methods.

I can explain about how to do this if required.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I manually create a new hash which includes `playlist_ids`, the created video is associated with the playlist. But for some reason the `playlist_ids` object isn't available in `video_params` even though it's available in `params`, with the same code as your last 3 lines above. Any further ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it matters but this is a sample project I created just to test this problem, so I used scaffolds to quickly generate the Videos and Playlists

Comment: Did you definitely add playlist_ids: [] to your permit list in the video_params method?

Comment: @StephenLead- in your JSON.stringify, make sure you are passing playlist_ids (an array of ids), not just playlist_id ( a single id).

Comment: @rlarcombe I've reproduced this by starting a brand new project, so I've  rewritten the question completely, taking on board your earlier advice (including ensuring that `playlist_ids` is an array) - but the problem persists. I'd be grateful for any further advice. thanks!

Comment: @StephenLead - could you please do raise params[:video].inspect before \@video = Video.new video_params in your create action, and post the result with your answer? I need to see what it coming through the params, before the permit whitelist.

Comment: @rlarcombe this returns `Parameters: {"title"=>"test video", "url"=>"http://www.youtube.com/987", "playlist_ids"=>[1], "video"=>{"title"=>"test video", "url"=>"http://www.youtube.com/987"}}`

Comment: @StephenLead - have updated my answer. I believe the problem is that JSON.stringify is not nesting the parameters within a node called "video", which is what your controller is expecting.